# How retrieve Mailgun Delivered Message in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

In my Node.js application, I followed the Mailgun docs https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-with-smtp-or-api for sending an email similar to the following:

```
mailgun.messages().send(data, (error, body) => {
  console.log(body);

// body is {id: some_mailgun_built_id, message: 'Queued. Thank You'}
// which I store the body.id in my database

});
```

The issue I am faced with is how can I access that same Mailgun response when I send an email with Laravel? The Mailgun docs don't provide any examples showing how to retrieve that data.

This is how I am sending emails with Laravel:

```
\Mail::to($recipients)->send(
  // this just renders my blade file which formats my email
  new SendEmail($email);
);
// ?? How to get Message was sent object here
```

If anyone knows of any solution it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and Welcome to SO!

Laravel has two events for the emails as explained in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#events): [`MessageSending`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Mail/Events/MessageSending.php) and [`MessageSent`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Mail/Events/MessageSent.php)

You can follow the [events official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/events) in order to listen for these specific events:

```php
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending' => [
        'My\Email\Listener',
    ],
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
        'My\Other\Listener',
    ],
];
```

You will receive as input the `Swift_message` which contains a header that is the Mailgun ID you're looking for. Let's have a look at the `MailgunTransport@send` source code in order to understand what's going on behind the scenes:

```php
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function send(Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage $message, &$failedRecipients = null)
{
     // [...]

     $response = $this->client->request(
         'POST',
         "https://{$this->endpoint}/v3/{$this->domain}/messages.mime",
         $this->payload($message, $to)
     );

     $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader(
         'X-Mailgun-Message-ID', $this->getMessageId($response) // <-- HERE LARAVEL SETS THE MESSAGE ID
     );

     // [...]
}
```

Looking for the same key in your listener you can recover the message ID that mailgun assigned to your e-mail. Unfortunately you can't access the entire Mailgun response but with the API you can easily retrieve your message.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this is a shot!

Comment: What is the $this->payload method refer to? Is that a part of Guzzle?

Comment: It refers to [this method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Mail/Transport/MailgunTransport.php#L93) of the `MailgunTransport` class. It just "prettifies" the response.

Comment: OK, I see and understand now. It might seem like a dumb question but how do I use the MailgunTransport class, and change my app to use that. Since currently my app uses the Mail Facade which then calls Illuminate\Mail\Mailer to send the email, and I'm not sure how to change that.

Comment: Do I just inject that in my event listener class?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#driver-prerequisites :)
Here you should find everything you need to configure mailgun

Comment: Also If making changes to the MailgunTransport will these changes get overwrite when I update with Composer?

Comment: Yes of course... You should extend that driver in your codebase... or write a new one and register it with it's own service provider and so on... But it's like reinventing the wheel IMHO....

Comment: Ok, I guess since I am using Laravel 5.7 it's best just to upgrade to version 6 where the code exists.

Comment: ??? The [Mailgun driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail) exists since version 4.2

Comment: Yes, but the code you mentioned in the MailgunTransport@send did not exist for me, that why I was confused.

Comment: Do you know I would then pass the $message->id from MailgunTransport to my event listener. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290352/how-to-pass-mailgun-id-create-in-mailguntransport-to-an-event-listener-in-larav  

Thanks for your help BTW I  appreciate it! :)

Comment: I'll have a look at that question. If you think that my answer was correct, feel free to accept it.