# How To Pass Mailgun ID create in MailgunTransport to an Event Listener, in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

In my Laravel application, I have an Event Listener that triggers when someone is added to a course, then emails that user "You've been added to course".

I am using Mailgun to send these emails, and in this Listener, I call `\Mail` which builds a blade file and sends the email to the users, which all works fine.

My issue is I want to store that Mailgun ID. Which in Laravel v6 gets added in `Illuminate\Mail\Transport\MailgunTransport@send` and I can access that ID by calling `$message->getId()` which I think can be found in `vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMessage.php`

How do I return `$message->getId()` so I can use it in my Listener?

In my Listener `\Mail` I call my Model to create the newly sent email record and I want to be able to store that ID.

Below is a link to my initial question which https://stackoverflow.com/users/2343305/ilgala was able to help out:

[How retrieve Mailgun Delivered Message in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269827/how-retrieve-mailgun-delivered-message-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered also to your old question. I think you're missunderstanding the process. I'll create a complete example down here for Laravel 6.x but it should be the same for the older versions.

**1. Configure mailgun**

That's the easy part. Just change the `services.php` file with the mailgun credentials and remember to require with composer the `guzzlehttp/guzzle` package, otherwise you won't be able to send e-mails. Then change the `.env` file and set the `MAIL_DRIVER` to `mailgun`. In this way Laravel will know that it has to use that driver to send e-mails.

**2. Create your logic**

Let's say you have to send an e-mail each time a customer creates and order. You will have an `OrderController` somewhere in your codebase with a `store` method that creates the order and send the email right after. Something like

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
  // Validate your request
  $this->validate([...]);

  // Create the order
  $order = new Order();
  $order->fill($request->only([...]));

  // Save order
  $order->save();

  // Send confirmation email;
  Mail::to(auth()->user())->send(new OrderCreated($order));
}
```

Since you setted the mailgun Driver, the `Mail` facade will automatically use the `MailgunTransport` class.

**3. Create the listener**

As explained in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59270747/2343305), set the listener in the `EventServiceProvider`. Than, once you created the listener you can retrieve the Mailgun ID as follows:

```php
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(MessageSent $event)
{
    // Retrieve mailgun ID from the message headers
    $id = $event->message->getHeaders()->get('X-Mailgun-Message-ID');
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @ilGala this example makes it much clearer for me, and I think I see my reason for confusing. I will give this a shot!